# Playing AVI files with the JMF

Tags: java, swing, jmf, avi

I have long been trying to use the Java Media Framework in order to play a video inside a JFrame. I have chosen the JMF, as it appears to have the structure that I like the most. I have been trying to play an AVI video, however it comes up with this error:

> Unable to handle format: H264, 854x480, FrameRate=29.9, Length=1229760 26 extra bytes
>     Unable to handle format: unknown, 48000.0 Hz, 0-bit, Stereo, Unsigned, 16000.0 frame rate, FrameSize=8192 bits

I do not understand this, as according to the [list of supported formats](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html), AVI files are supported by the JMF. Could somebody please tell me what the problem could be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of media types is flawed.  Most media are 'container formats', meaning that the content might be encoded using a number of different compression formats.  That list you linked to, shows file types (like AVI or MOV) in **bold** then ***below that*** it shows the encodings that are supported for that container format.

If you search down the list, you will see that H.261 & H.263 are supported as a MOV, but there is no listing (for any file-type) for H.264.

JMF was a great API back in the day, but it is lack of support for newer (more highly compressed) codecs that make it useless for general use in the modern world.

(You do realize it was abandoned **over 10 years ago,** right?)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. To answer your question, yes I do realise that the JMF was abandoned. When I looked at the information, I must admit that I was careless. Do you have any suggestions for an alternative solution?